# kubectl or bash is ignoring KUBECONFIG env variable

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, wsl-2

I am setting `KUBECONFIG` variable, but kubectl is not using this variable and instead using the default config file.

Setting variable as below -

```
$export KUBECONFIG=./my-k8s-token.config
```

next am running get pods as below -

```
$ kubectl.exe get pods -v 8
I1211 22:08:39.175597    1920 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file C:\Users\myuserhome/.kube/config
I1211 22:08:39.186378    1920 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500
I1211 22:08:39.187586    1920 round_trippers.go:423] Request Headers:
```

As you can see above, kubectl is still using the default config file: `C:\Users\myuserhome/.kube/config`.

How can i fix this. How can i make kubectl read the config file from KUBECONFIG variable.

Note: If you are wondering why there is .exe extension for kubectl, the answer is I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu.

Comment: Trye to use an absolute path instead of a relative one

Comment: What's `$export`? Typo?

Comment: 1. set KUBECONFIG variable in the terminal you are running kubectl (you ran export command in linux terminal but I see you used kubectl from a windows terminal).
2. export command is for temporarily setting variables, you lose the variable if you exit the terminal.
3. use an absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

I could solve the issue by using `kubectl` which i installed using offical documentation - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-using-native-package-management.

Now on using kubectl instead of kubectl.exe I am able to use KUBECONFIG env variable.

Comment: if you feel this answer helps you, please consider upvoting Q&A.